# Executing a T4 text template in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, code-generation, t4, texttemplate

I created a T4 text template (`.tt`) file in Visual Studio Code, but unlike Visual Studio 2017 (or 2015 ,...) it won't generate the output file after saving the `.tt` file. How can I generate the output in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code(VsCode) not VS2017.

Comment: any luck on this?

Comment: Try this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aisoftware.tt-processor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solution is not exactly what you asked, but it may be useful in many scenarios (on Windows OS only).

You can create a task in Visual Studio Code and run `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\TextTransform.exe`. If you don't have Visual Studio you can copy this file to your project folder and execute it from that location.

Any extension that can run a `.exe` file can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you so desire (depends on how much you want it!) it looks like you could create your own app based upon the classes Microsoft uses for TextTransform.exe, Microsoft has written a walkthrough of how to do it:

*[Walkthrough: Create a Custom Text Template Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-text-template-host?view=vs-2017)*

> If you want to perform text transformation as part of a build process,
>   consider using the MSBuild text transformation task. For more
>   information, see Code Generation in a Build Process. In a machine on
>   which Visual Studio is installed, you can also write an application or
>   Visual Studio Extension that can transform text templates. For more
>   information, see Processing Text Templates by using a Custom Host.

I'm not sure however if the assemblies it mentions

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.*.0

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Interfaces.10.0 and later versions

are .NET standard / .NET Core, i.e. if they are cross platform.